# How to clear zend metadata cache using tags

Tags: zend-framework, caching, redis, metadata

I'm using redis cache backend, I would like to clean metadata cache - it is there some kind of default tag(s) for zend metadatas so I could remove cache without flushing all data?

Answer (score 0):

components such as `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` don't use tags to save objects into the cache, so I believe trying to clean the cache the the empty tag should do it:

```
$cache->clean(
  Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG,
  array('')
);
```